# What is the easiest way to parse XML in ActionScript3/Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

What is the easiest way to parse XML in ActionScript3/Flex ?

Answer (score 4):

By using e4X syntax.

Here are a few links to documentation that may help you:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#top

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e71.html

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-357.htm

Answer (score 0):

We have an XML parser and tutorial here:
http://forea.ch/blog/2010/05/17/utils-parsing-xml/

We also have an XML creator, so you just create the data objects that your application needs and don't have to worry about XML if, for example, you're using XML for configuration data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse a XML to a Object .

you can use [FLEXXB](http://code.google.com/p/flexxb/) .its a wonderful lib.